# Which text-based web browser is the best handling graphic options to select?

Tags: web-browser, web, installer

I tried Lynx.  But I was not able to choose one of the three columns that appear in a normal web browser for a critical operation of installing/configuring Cloudera.

I am trying to install Cloudera 5.  There is an initial Cloudera Manager Wizard that must be used after Cloudera is installed.  In the series of web UI options, there are three editions to choose from (free, enterprise etc.).  With a web UI, you choose one option and click Next.  With Lynx, you cannot select any option.  Clicking a button to continue won't even go to the next page.  I want to check the Free version.  But as I press the down key, I never reach the "Free Edition" option.  I never reach any option for the different versions.  One selection is mandatory to proceed.  Lynx does not seem to be useful here.

Maybe the Cloudera Manager Wizard was not meant to be used with Lynx.  Is there a text-based browser that has more features?

(I corrected the posting.  The first comment caught a typo.)

Comment: In your last sentence, don't you rather mean "text-based"? I'd assume web-browsers should all be web-based somehow :) Further: OS is Linux, and price is "free"? Just guessing, your question lacks those details. // Rarely using them with graphics, but there are two more coming to my mind: [Links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_%28web_browser%29) and [eLinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elinks). I'd give the former a try (still maintained, and the most likely candidate to solve your issue). Cannot say for sure, too long ago I last used it ;)

Comment: links2 actually allows graphics and mouse use, IF you have a local X server or have set up svgalib...  Of course, if you have a local X server you can always ssh in and export your display back....